# Invalid root in registry key error message when trying to read/write a key in HKLM path of the registry

Tags: vbscript, registry, hp-uft

I have tried the solution from "[update registry using VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416995/update-registry-using-vbs)", but it still gives the same error message:

> WshShell.RegWrite: Invalid root in registry key

You should change LegalNoticeText value together with LegalNoticeCaption one. Under the
 `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\`
 Registry key there both values reside as well. For this case (if a computer is not connected to a domain or with group policy disabled) should work next script.

I am trying to do it in UFT 12.5 using VBScript.

Environment:

- UFT 12.5
- Windows 2012 Server

Comment: Please post the code you are using to try and make this change.  Worth noting that the other answer you have linked to suggests you need to execute the vbscript as an administrator - you don't mention if you have tried this or not?

Comment: Please find the below script that I am trying to execute.

Comment: @Dave  Please find the below script that I am trying to execute.  'Script to access the Windows Registry
Dim objShell, RegLocate
'create windows shell object
 Set objshell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 
'disable pop up blocker in IE if enabled
 'RegLocate ="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows\PopupMgr"
 RegLocate ="HKLM\SOFTWARE\MBS\Environment"
 print objshell.RegRead(RegLocate)

Comment: @Dave  I have tried to run UFT as admin but to no avail.  Then I tried the below code to elevate the privileges with code. 
Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1  

But it is giving error messages like "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'WScript.FullName' "

Comment: Please edit the question (link underneath the tags) and insert the code there.  It looks to me like you're trying to insert pure `vbscript` into a `UFT` script - which is why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the code that performs the registry write steps in a separate `vbs` file and use the following code to run it as admin from the UFT script:

```
myVbsFilePath = "C:\temp\something.vbs"

Dim WShell : Set WShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")    
WShell.ShellExecute "C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe", """" & myVbsFilePath & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
```

The `WScript` attributes you're trying to refer to would require the `vbscript` to be run by `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`, whereas you are trying to run this from `UFT` instead, where things like `WScript.FullName` and `WScript.ScriptFullName` are not available.

You may need to amend the path provided to `cscript.exe` in my example code above for your own system.

Comment: Thank You, but that dint resolve that issue. But something else did.

Comment: @VikramGanapathi if you found a different solution, it's encouraged to post your own answer detailing what the issue was and how you solved it - this allows others to benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run as admin with this:

```
RunAsAdmin()
Function RunAsAdmin()
    If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
        WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & " RunAsAdministrator",,"runas", 1
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function
```