# Invalid Root in Registry Key (VBScript)

Tags: vbscript

i have made a simple VBScript file that enables Task Manager.
but when i execute it , i get error "Invalid Root In Registry Key"
why?

```
set Shell=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
shell.regwrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\DisableTaskMgr","0","REG_DWORD"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update registry using VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416995/update-registry-using-vbs)

Comment: You need to run the with Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code below WScript.Shell:

```
RunAsAdmin()
Function RunAsAdmin()
    If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
        WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & " RunAsAdministrator",,"runas", 1
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Function
```

This will run the script as admin. If it does not work then check your registry path because it is probably incorrect.

Comment: its work for me please set as answer